# Can I use DICOM Library's for DICONDE?

Tags: c#, dicom

I know that DICOM and DICONDE are basicly the same. DICOM for medicine, DICONDE for industry.
For DICOM I use the FellowOak DICOM Library and my question is if I can use it for DICONDE too and if yes, is it possible to change the Tag-Names and how can I change the Tag-Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be able to use it. DICOMDE is based on DICOM standard encoding with some additional tags and extension to existing DICOM standard IODs such as Digital X-Ray Image.

It would be best if your DICOM library of choice allows you to define additional DICOM tags, renaming of strings representing existing DICOM tags and redefining the IOD Class with the attributes and restrictions added by DICOMDE standard to simplify presentation of data to your end-user.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use Fellow Oak and I can create new Tags